# How to set up a single page application with durandal and MVC areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, durandal

I would like to set up a single page application in MVC with a dashboard and pluginable apps. It would be nice if these pluginable apps could be separate projects using MVC areas. It would then also be great if the viewmodels and views for these apps could reside inside their project.

All info I've found so far about setting up Durandal and routing has all views and viewmodels inside a single App folder. How could I split this out and set up the routing?